# Tips for using react-native-ble-manager to retrieve fitness data from a smartwatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, bluetooth-lowenergy

How can I retrieve calories, heart rate, and other fitness detail data from my connected smartwatch using react-native-ble-manager in a React Native application?

I am developing a fitness tracking application in React Native, and I need to fetch data such as calories burned and heart rate from my connected smartwatch. I am using the react-native-ble-manager package to handle Bluetooth communication. However, I am facing difficulties in retrieving the desired fitness detail data from the smartwatch. I would appreciate guidance on how to accomplish this task.
Specifically, I would like to know:
How can I establish a connection between my React Native application and the smartwatch using react-native-ble-manager?
Which Bluetooth services and characteristics should I target to retrieve the calories, heart rate, and other fitness detail data?
What specific steps or commands should I use with react-native-ble-manager to read the relevant data from the smartwatch's services and characteristics?
Are there any specific considerations or prerequisites for successfully retrieving fitness data from a smartwatch, such as authentication or permission requirements?
Once the data is read, how can I interpret and process it to extract meaningful information, such as calculating the calories burned or displaying the heart rate in my application?
I would appreciate any example code snippets or explanations that can help me understand how to retrieve the fitness detail data from my connected smartwatch using react-native-ble-manager. Below is my code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  NativeModules,
  NativeEventEmitter,
  Platform,
  PermissionsAndroid,
  FlatList,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Pressable,
} from 'react-native';

import {Colors} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

const SECONDS_TO_SCAN_FOR = 7;
const SERVICE_UUIDS: string[] = [];
const ALLOW_DUPLICATES = true;

import BleManager, {
  BleDisconnectPeripheralEvent,
  BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristicEvent,
  BleScanCallbackType,
  BleScanMatchMode,
  BleScanMode,
  Peripheral,
} from 'react-native-ble-manager';
import {debugLog} from './src/Common/commonfunction';

const BleManagerModule = NativeModules.BleManager;
const bleManagerEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(BleManagerModule);

declare module 'react-native-ble-manager' {
  // enrich local contract with custom state properties needed by App.tsx
  interface Peripheral {
    connected?: boolean;
    connecting?: boolean;
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [isScanning, setIsScanning] = useState(false);
  const [peripherals, setPeripherals] = useState(
    new Map<Peripheral['id'], Peripheral>(),
  );

  console.log('peripherals map updated', [...peripherals.entries()]);

  const addOrUpdatePeripheral = (id: string, updatedPeripheral: Peripheral) => {
    // new Map() enables changing the reference & refreshing UI.
    // TOFIX not efficient.
    setPeripherals(map => new Map(map.set(id, updatedPeripheral)));
  };

  const startScan = () => {
    if (!isScanning) {
      // reset found peripherals before scan
      setPeripherals(new Map<Peripheral['id'], Peripheral>());

      try {
        console.log('[startScan] starting scan...');
        setIsScanning(true);
        BleManager.scan(SERVICE_UUIDS, SECONDS_TO_SCAN_FOR, ALLOW_DUPLICATES, {
          matchMode: BleScanMatchMode.Sticky,
          scanMode: BleScanMode.LowLatency,
          callbackType: BleScanCallbackType.AllMatches,
        })
          .then(() => {
            console.log('[startScan] scan promise returned successfully.');
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.error('[startScan] ble scan returned in error', err);
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('[startScan] ble scan error thrown', error);
      }
    }
  };

  const handleStopScan = () => {
    setIsScanning(false);
    console.log('[handleStopScan] scan is stopped.');
  };

  const handleDisconnectedPeripheral = (
    event: BleDisconnectPeripheralEvent,
  ) => {
    let peripheral = peripherals.get(event.peripheral);
    if (peripheral) {
      console.log(
        `[handleDisconnectedPeripheral][${peripheral.id}] previously connected peripheral is disconnected.`,
        event.peripheral,
      );
      addOrUpdatePeripheral(peripheral.id, {...peripheral, connected: false});
    }
    console.log(
      `[handleDisconnectedPeripheral][${event.peripheral}] disconnected.`,
    );
  };

  const handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic = (
    data: BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristicEvent,
  ) => {
    console.log(
      `[handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic] received data from '${data.peripheral}' with characteristic='${data.characteristic}' and value='${data.value}'`,
    );
  };

  const handleDiscoverPeripheral = (peripheral: Peripheral) => {
    console.log('[handleDiscoverPeripheral] new BLE peripheral=', peripheral);
    if (!peripheral.name) {
      peripheral.name = 'NO NAME';
    }
    addOrUpdatePeripheral(peripheral.id, peripheral);
  };

  const togglePeripheralConnection = async (peripheral: Peripheral) => {
    // if (peripheral && peripheral.connected) {
    //   try {
    //     await BleManager.disconnect(peripheral.id);
    //   } catch (error) {
    //     console.error(
    //       `[togglePeripheralConnection][${peripheral.id}] error when trying to disconnect device.`,
    //       error,
    //     );
    //   }
    // } else {
    await connectPeripheral(peripheral);
    // }
  };

  const retrieveConnected = async () => {
    try {
      const connectedPeripherals = await BleManager.getConnectedPeripherals();
      if (connectedPeripherals.length === 0) {
        console.warn('[retrieveConnected] No connected peripherals found.');
        return;
      }

      console.log(
        '[retrieveConnected] connectedPeripherals',
        connectedPeripherals,
      );

      for (var i = 0; i < connectedPeripherals.length; i++) {
        var peripheral = connectedPeripherals[i];
        addOrUpdatePeripheral(peripheral.id, {...peripheral, connected: true});
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        '[retrieveConnected] unable to retrieve connected peripherals.',
        error,
      );
    }
  };

  const connectPeripheral = async (peripheral: Peripheral) => {
    try {
      if (peripheral) {
        addOrUpdatePeripheral(peripheral.id, {...peripheral, connecting: true});

        await BleManager.connect(peripheral.id);
        console.log(`[connectPeripheral][${peripheral.id}] connected.`);

        addOrUpdatePeripheral(peripheral.id, {
          ...peripheral,
          connecting: false,
          connected: true,
        });

        // before retrieving services, it is often a good idea to let bonding & connection finish properly
        await sleep(900);

        /* Test read current RSSI value, retrieve services first */
        const peripheralData = await BleManager.retrieveServices(peripheral.id);
        console.log(
          `[connectPeripheral][${peripheral.id}] retrieved peripheral services`,
          peripheralData,
        );

        const rssi = await BleManager.readRSSI(peripheral.id);
        console.log(
          `[connectPeripheral][${peripheral.id}] retrieved current RSSI value: ${rssi}.`,
        );

        if (peripheralData.characteristics) {
          for (let characteristic of peripheralData.characteristics) {
            if (characteristic.descriptors) {
              for (let descriptor of characteristic.descriptors) {
                try {
                  let data = await BleManager.readDescriptor(
                    peripheral.id,
                    characteristic.service,
                    characteristic.characteristic,
                    descriptor.uuid,
                  );
                  debugLog(characteristic.characteristic);
                  console.log(
                    `[connectPeripheral][${peripheral.id}] descriptor read as:`,
                    data,
                  );
                } catch (error) {
                  console.error(
                    `[connectPeripheral][${peripheral.id}] failed to retrieve descriptor ${descriptor} for characteristic ${characteristic}:`,
                    error,
                  );
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }

        let p = peripherals.get(peripheral.id);
        if (p) {
          addOrUpdatePeripheral(peripheral.id, {...peripheral, rssi});
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        `[connectPeripheral][${peripheral.id}] connectPeripheral error`,
        error,
      );
    }
  };

  function sleep(ms: number) {
    return new Promise<void>(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      BleManager.start({showAlert: false})
        .then(() => console.log('BleManager started.'))
        .catch(error =>
          console.error('BeManager could not be started.', error),
        );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('unexpected error starting BleManager.', error);
      return;
    }

    const listeners = [
      bleManagerEmitter.addListener(
        'BleManagerDiscoverPeripheral',
        handleDiscoverPeripheral,
      ),
      bleManagerEmitter.addListener('BleManagerStopScan', handleStopScan),
      bleManagerEmitter.addListener(
        'BleManagerDisconnectPeripheral',
        handleDisconnectedPeripheral,
      ),
      bleManagerEmitter.addListener(
        'BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic',
        handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic,
      ),
    ];

    handleAndroidPermissions();
    BleManager.retrieveServices('F7:CE:37:10:XXXXXX').then(res => {
      debugLog(res.characteristics[16].characteristic);
      BleManager.requestConnectionPriority('F7:CE:37:10:XXXXX', 'high').then(
        res => {
          debugLog('priority');
          debugLog(res);
        },
      );
      BleManager.read(
        'F7:CE:37:10:XXXX',
        res.characteristics[16].service,
        res.characteristics[16].characteristic,
      )
        .then(res => {
          debugLog('=======>+heart');
          debugLog(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          debugLog(err);
        });
    });

    // return () => {
    //   console.log('[app] main component unmounting. Removing listeners...');
    //   for (const listener of listeners) {
    //     listener.remove();
    //   }
    // };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const handleAndroidPermissions = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 31) {
      PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
      ]).then(result => {
        if (result) {
          console.log(
            '[handleAndroidPermissions] User accepts runtime permissions android 12+',
          );
        } else {
          console.error(
            '[handleAndroidPermissions] User refuses runtime permissions android 12+',
          );
        }
      });
    } else if (Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 23) {
      PermissionsAndroid.check(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      ).then(checkResult => {
        if (checkResult) {
          console.log(
            '[handleAndroidPermissions] runtime permission Android <12 already OK',
          );
        } else {
          PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
          ).then(requestResult => {
            if (requestResult) {
              console.log(
                '[handleAndroidPermissions] User accepts runtime permission android <12',
              );
            } else {
              console.error(
                '[handleAndroidPermissions] User refuses runtime permission android <12',
              );
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };

  const renderItem = ({item}: {item: Peripheral}) => {
    const backgroundColor = item.connected ? '#069400' : Colors.white;
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        underlayColor="#0082FC"
        onPress={() => togglePeripheralConnection(item)}>
        <View style={[styles.row, {backgroundColor}]}>
          <Text style={styles.peripheralName}>
            {/* completeLocalName (item.name) & shortAdvertisingName (advertising.localName) may not always be the same */}
            {item.name} - {item?.advertising?.localName}
            {item.connecting && ' - Connecting...'}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.rssi}>RSSI: {item.rssi}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.peripheralId}>{item.id}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar />
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.body}>
        <Pressable style={styles.scanButton} onPress={startScan}>
          <Text style={styles.scanButtonText}>
            {isScanning ? 'Scanning...' : 'Scan Bluetooth'}
          </Text>
        </Pressable>

        <Pressable style={styles.scanButton} onPress={retrieveConnected}>
          <Text style={styles.scanButtonText}>
            {'Retrieve connected peripherals'}
          </Text>
        </Pressable>

        {Array.from(peripherals.values()).length === 0 && (
          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text style={styles.noPeripherals}>
              No Peripherals, press "Scan Bluetooth" above.
            </Text>
          </View>
        )}

        <FlatList
          data={Array.from(peripherals.values())}
          contentContainerStyle={{rowGap: 12}}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

const boxShadow = {
  shadowColor: '#000',
  shadowOffset: {
    width: 0,
    height: 2,
  },
  shadowOpacity: 0.25,
  shadowRadius: 3.84,
  elevation: 5,
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  engine: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 10,
    bottom: 0,
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  scanButton: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#0a398a',
    margin: 10,
    borderRadius: 12,
    ...boxShadow,
  },
  scanButtonText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    letterSpacing: 0.25,
    color: Colors.white,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: '#0082FC',
    flex: 1,
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: Colors.dark,
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  footer: {
    color: Colors.dark,
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '600',
    padding: 4,
    paddingRight: 12,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
  peripheralName: {
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: 10,
  },
  rssi: {
    fontSize: 12,
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: 2,
  },
  peripheralId: {
    fontSize: 12,
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: 2,
    paddingBottom: 20,
  },
  row: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    borderRadius: 20,
    ...boxShadow,
  },
  noPeripherals: {
    margin: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: Colors.white,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: I do not know any smartwatch that offers services to directly access the information you need. They all work with a specific app (for example Galaxy Wearable) to do the connection and reading of the data via proprietary services.